# Declaring char array in Ruby FFI

Tags: c, ruby, callback, ruby-ffi

I have the following C code:

```
typedef void (*mycallback) (char buf[128]);
void take_callback(mycallback cb)
{
}
```

I've written the equivalent Ruby FFI declarations as below (following advice for structs on [FFI wiki](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Structs)):

```
  callback :mycallback, [[:char, 128]], :void
  attach_function :take_callback, [:mycallback], :void
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
`find_type': unable to resolve type '[:char, 128]' (TypeError)
```

It seems I'm not declaring the char array in the callback correctly. From the way arrays work in function arguments in C, I think I should use `:pointer` instead of `[:char, 128]` . But I'm not sure about the peculiarities of FFI. What's really the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays aren't passed by value in C -- they're passed as pointers to the first element, so `:pointer` (or whatever is ordinarily used for `char *`) should be correct.

Comment: I just found this wiki page: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Callbacks which confirms that I should use :pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `:pointer` is the correct way for this kind of parameter, not only for callbacks, but in general. For example this isn't possible, too: `typedef [:char, 128], :buffer_128`. The only exception are `FFI::Struct` layouts where these types are allowed.

This is a little bit frustrating, especially since FFI so seamlessly supports null termined strings (via `:string`). Fortunately it is still relatively ease to work with `:pointer` arguments, too.

I am using this helper in some of my projects:

```rb
def with_buffer(size, clear: true, &)
  FFI::MemoryPointer.new(:char, size, clear) do |buffer|
    yield buffer
    return buffer.read_string
  end
end
```

Usage example: (from a CEC Ruby library I'm working on, stripped for clarity)

```rb
name = with_buffer(13) { |buffer| libcec_get_device_osd_name(*, buffer) }
```

Or when the called function wants to know the buffer size and you don't want to repeat that information:

```rb
cec_version = 
  with_buffer(50) do |buffer| 
    libcec_cec_version_to_string(*, buffer, buffer.size) # buffer.size == 50
  end
```

Perhaps this is useful to someone...